# Return bounding box for each grid square in numpy meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates

I have a function that takes a bounding box (the lower left and upper right coordinates), and the number of grid squares to split the grid into on each axis. The function returns a list of coordinates representing the lower left corner of each grid square.

```
def grid(min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y, split_grid_x, split_grid_y):
    x = np.linspace(min_x, max_x, split_grid_x)
    y = np.linspace(min_y, max_y, split_grid_y)
    xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    grid = np.hstack((xv.reshape((xv.size, 1)), yv.reshape((yv.size, 1))))
    return grid.tolist()
```

For example:

```
grid(0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3)
```

Returns:

```
[[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0], [2.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 1.0], [0.0, 2.0], [1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 2.0]]
```

What I would like is for the function to return the bounding box of each grid square. For example, the first element in the above array would return `[0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0]`.

I hope I've explained this effectively, let me know if you need clarification. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I built a little optimized way but it worked for me:

```
div_lat = np.linspace(lat_min, lat_max, 5)
div_lon = np.linspace(lon_min, lon_max, 5)
  
x, y = np.meshgrid(div_lon, div_lat)
  
lista_comb = np.hstack((x.reshape((x.size,1)),y.reshape((y.size,1))))
grid_lons, grid_lats = np.array(lista_comb).T

lista_lons = []
for i in range(len(div_lon)):
    try:
        lst = [div_lon[i], div_lon[i+1]]
        lista_lons.append(lst)
    except:
        break


lista_lats = []
for i in range(len(div_lat)):
    try:
        lst = [div_lat[i], div_lat[i+1]]
        lista_lats.append(lst)
    except:
        break


lista_final = []
for lst_lat in lista_lats:
    for lst_lon in lista_lons:
        lista_final.append(lst_lon + lst_lat)


bb_dict = {}

for i, bb in enumerate(lista_final):
    bb_dict[i+1] = {
        'lon_min': round(bb[0], 2),
        'lon_max': round(bb[1], 2),
        'lat_min': round(bb[2], 2),
        'lat_max': round(bb[3], 2)
    }
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answer and provide an explanation. You also could have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).